# How to change value of XML document in linq by an attribute value?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, replace

Sample XML File

```
<SiEventSchedule deleteStart="2012/01/21 00:00:00" deleteEnd="2012/01/21 23:59:59">
</SiEventSchedule>
```

Code:

```
var el = doc.Descendants(ns + "SiEventSchedule").Select(x => x.Attribute("deleteStart").Value).First();
string[] s = el.ToString().Split(' ');
s[0] = today.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
String s5 = String.Join(" ", s);
el.Replace(el, s5); // This line is not working
```

Only the last line of the code is not working, everything else is working.
Can anyone please suggest how to update this value?

```
<SiEventSchedule deleteStart="2012/01/21 00:00:00" deleteEnd="2012/01/21 23:59:59">
</SiEventSchedule>
```

Comment: el.Value should do the trick!?

Comment: @ Steen  No it is not working with el.Value

Comment: Remove the .Value in the select, you don't want to select the string/value, you want to select the attribute. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what it is you're trying to do with the select, but if you want to change the value of the attribute, this is how:

```
        XAttribute attr = doc.Descendants(ns + "SiEventSchedule").Select(x => x.Attribute("deleteStart")).First();
        attr.SetValue(attr.Value.Replace(oldValue, newValue));
```

Comment: Sorry, a bit too quick, now it does.

Comment: @Saman: If it's working you can accept the answer by clicking the check mark on the left side to the answer !!

Answer (score 0):

That ?

```
using System.Xml.Linq; 

XDocument xmlFile = XDocument.Load("books.xml");  

var query = from c in xmlFile.Elements("catalog").Elements("book")     
            select c;  

foreach (XElement book in query)  
{ 
   book.Attribute("attr1").Value = "MyNewValue"; 
} 

xmlFile.Save("books.xml");
```

i hope this help